# Grails : How do you make services available inside services?

Tags: grails

I am currently running into an issue where I am attempting to use a service within a service however the service is null

```
class ApplicationService{
    def someService

    def someMethod(){
        someService.method()//null on someService
    }
}
```

Is there additional wiring that I need to perform for this to work? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What type is someService?   Try putting that type instead of `def`.  Also, is this ApplicationService class in the services directory?  If not, you won't get automatic dependency injection.

Comment: That doesn't work for me.

Comment: one of your "services" is not a service at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by using the **grailsApplication** and loading the service.

```
if(!someService){
    someService = grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass("org.company.SomeService").newInstance()
}
```

Comment: This is not a good way to inject a service.  Calling `newInstance()` will not give you all the autowired parts of the service class you're expecting.  Where in your project structure is `ApplicationService` located?  Can you give the path?

Answer (score 0):

The most possible explanation i here is, the class behind SomeService is not a Grails service artefact thus you cannot just inject it like that.

Double check on the source code whether that class is really a service or just a Groovy class in src/groovy. The framework will treat these two differently.

Also do not attempt to inject service with manually creating the instance like your answer, that is not the correct way to do dependency injection in Grails (or in Spring).